# Is there any reason here?

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #one{
                background-color: brown;
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 0;
            }
            #two{
                background-color: rgb(86, 74, 153);
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 0;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="one">
            <h1>heading</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            <h2>welcome section</h2>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

why do `margin-top: 0`and `margin-bottom: 0` not working in css here? is there any rule like this in css?if i give border to both, it works. also when i give border of 1px, height of div is increasing automatically and margin goes zero but without border i can not set margin zero. why? please give brief discription of this rule.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. _“Is there any reason here?”_ is an absolutely terrible question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**h** elements have default margins. your **h1** and **h2** cause it.

```
#one h1, #two h2 {
   margin-top:0;
   margin-bottom:0;
}
```